# Algolia sorting by geolocation in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, geolocation, algolia

I have a problem with Algolia geolocation sorting in iOS App.
I need to display all documents in a range of 100 km from the user location.
I have multiple documents in my Indice. The document looks like this:

```
"document": {
    "price": 5000,
    "unit": "cały projekt",
    "_geoloc": {
      "lat": 54.5,
      "lng": 18.55
    },
    "title": "Test ogloszenia",
    "range": 0,
    "activeFrom": {
      "_seconds": 1597042800,
      "_nanoseconds": 0
    }
}
```

In my Algolia Ranking and Sorting, I have default set GEO.

My Swift code for sorting locations looks like below:

```
func getAnnouncesLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping ([Announcement]) -> ()) {
        var announcementsArray = [Announcement]()
        let query = Query(query: "")
        
        
        query.aroundLatLng = LatLng(lat: location.latitude, lng: location.longitude)
        query.aroundRadius = .explicit(100000) // 100 km
        collectionIndex = searchClient.index(withName: "products_geolocation")
        collectionIndex.search(query) { (content, error) in
            guard let content = content else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    
                }
                  
                return
            }
            print("HITS \(content)")
        }
     }
```

The code doesn't return any error but the content is empty.
Another sorting like by price works perfectly. The only problem is with geolocation.
If that can help to set sorting by the price I need to add a sort-by attribute like this: `document.price` in Dashboard.

I am saving data to Algolia from my server in Node.js and there I am creating `_geoloc` value.
The latitude and longitude are hardcoded for testing so there isn’t a problem with async.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in my project.
While sending the document to Algolia I send like this:

```
   const record = {
        objectID: doc.id,
        document: document
    };
```

where `document` contained all properties and also `_geoloc` property. After some investigation, I separated `_geoloc`  from the document I sent it like below:

```
   const record = {
        objectID: doc.id,
        document: document,
        _geoloc: coordinates

    };
```

Now everything works fine.

Cheers